# How should one go about moving from two nearly identical controller actions to one action that handles both necessary tasks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, refactoring, dry

I have the following Actions:

```
public ActionResult ProductList(int category)
{
    IEnumerable<Product> productList = repository.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == category);
    return PartialView("ProductList", productList);
}

public ActionResult CategoryList(int parentCategory)
{
    IEnumerable<Category> categoryList = repository.Categories.Where(p => p.ParentCategoryId == parentCategory);
    return PartialView("CategoryList", categoryList);
}
```

That build the following PartialViews:

```
@model POS.Domain.Entities.Product

<div class = "item">
    <h3>@Model.Name</h3>
    @Model.Description
    @Model.Category.Name
    <h4>@Model.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
</div>

@model POS.Domain.Entities.Category

<div class = "category" id= "@Model.CategoryId">
    <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
    <a href='/get-partial-view'>Get Products from the category: @Model.Name </a>
    <div class="divResult">
    </div>
</div>
```

and are tested with the following unit tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ProductListReturnsAppropriateProducts()
{
    // Arrange - create a controller
    var controller = new ProductController(_mockRepository.Object);

    // Action
    var result = (PartialViewResult) controller.ProductList(2);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(((IEnumerable<Product>) result.ViewData.Model).Count(), 2);
    Assert.IsTrue(((IEnumerable<Product>) result.ViewData.Model).Count(o => o.Name == "P4") == 1);
}

[TestMethod]
public void CategoryListReturnsAppropriateCategories()
{
    // Arrange - create a controller
    var controller = new ProductController(_mockRepository.Object);

    // Action
    var result = (PartialViewResult) controller.CategoryList(2);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(((IEnumerable<Category>) result.ViewData.Model).Count(), 3);
    Assert.IsTrue(((IEnumerable<Category>) result.ViewData.Model).Count(o => o.Name == "C4") == 1);
}
```

This is almost complete duplication - I want to learn to adhere more closely to the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

My actions do almost the same thing - except I need one to generate a list of products and one a list of categories. . .  (this is ultimately used to generate a page that lists categories that users can click to see all products within those categories).

There must be a way to consolidate these nearly duplicate methods into one method that can handle products vs categories appropriately.  How should I go about moving from having these two separate actions into having one action that handles both `products` and `categories`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are taking DRY a bit too far.. this is boilerplate code yes.. but it's dealing with different entities and should stay separated.

By combining them together you are going to break the single responsibility principle.  If you need to change how one works you should not have to change anything related to to the other.